# python `csv` library. writerows(['a', 'b']) is putting 2 rows into the csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I just tried to put single row into the csv file.

```
with open("output.csv", "wb") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(['a', 'b')
```

Expected CSV Output

```
[a, b]
```

Actual CSV Output

```
[a]
[b]
```

Comment: You're missing a bracket after 'b'

Answer (score 1):

`writerows()` writes each element in the input iterable as a new row

If you want a single row "a, b" add an additional level of nesting to your list:

```
with open("output.csv", "wb") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows([['a', 'b']])
```

Additionally if you only want to write a single row you can do what TeeKea suggests in his answer and use `writerow()`,

`writerows(iterable)` essentially functions as:

```
for item in iterable:
    writer.writerow(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, if you supply `['a', 'b']` to `writerows`, you should get this error:

> _csv.Error: iterable expected, not int

Second, if you open the file with the `wb` mode, you should also be getting the following error when you write a list to it:

> TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Therefore, to write the list `['a', 'b']` to a csv file, you would probably need to open the file in a `w` mode and use `writerow` instead of `writerows`, as follows:

```
with open("output.csv", "w") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(['a', 'b'])
```